# Ajustar Imagem/Bitmap à ImageView ou ajustar a ImageView à Imagem/Bitmap

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

Estou tentando criar uma tela de menu mais ou menos assim:

[image: Layout que fiz usando Adobe XD CC]

Para fazer esse corte na diagonal, eu fiz essa imagem para ficar em cima do background:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, no Android Studio, eu não consigo dimensionar a imagem para que ocupe o espaço necessário na tela, estou usando o **Constraint Layout** e ao tentar aumentar a imagem, mesmo com uma imagem de **alta resolução** ela fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ela não aumenta certo, já tentei mexer em várias configurações como: **ScaleType**, **AdjustViewBounds**, **cropToPadding**, estou o dia todo atrás disso e até agora nada

Segue o código XML dela:

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="616dp"
    android:layout_height="449dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_diag" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Ao definir valores absolutos para `android:layout_width` e `android:layout_height` a ImageView será apresentada com essas dimensões.

- Se quer que a **ImageView** se ajuste às dimensões do *layout* que a contém deve usar `match_parent` e, eventualmente, `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`.

  ```
  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_diag" />
  ```
- Se quer que a **imagem** se ajuste ao tamanho da *ImageView* poderá de ter de usar um dos tipos de [android:scaleType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html).
  O tipo a usar dependerá do tamanho e formato da imagem e do resultado final que quer obter(com ou sem deformação, imagem cortada ou não).

Comment: Olá, Ramaral, obrigado pela ajuda! Porém ainda não resolveu o problema. 
Veja como ficou: https://image.prntscr.com/image/yfsTAtjLRHGWvMaJgsSQZw.png

Comment: Veja as considerações adicionadas à resposta.