# Não consigo ajustar o tamanho da imagem ao layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Olá gostaria de alterar o layoutgravity da imagem, que sempre irá ficar preenchida nos lados e no topo. Altero o layoutgravity mas não muda nada.
Exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da Tela:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.aluno.tiposdeenergia.solar"
    android:background="@mipmap/background_foto1">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="230dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/energiasolar_foto2" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="monospace"
                android:text="Fontes de Energia Sustentáveis no Brasil"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/EnergiaSolar_Text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
                android:text="@string/Solar"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: você quer que ela fique preenchida em cima dos lados ou como é? explica o seu problema e o que você quer, porque provavelmente não vai nem precisar mexer no layout gravity

Comment: fique preenchida em cima e nos lados e sempre na posiçao do topo

Comment: eu tento usar o matchparent na altura da imagem mas não preenche, só preenche todo quando ponho 230dp

Comment: Então mano, a imagem ela tem o tamanho dela, e quando você coloca na imageview com as dimensões diferentes da imagem ela não preenche mesmo não, faz o seguinte vá em layout-weight e seta 1 e me diz se funcionou

Comment: Não mudou nada, nem com a altura em matchparent ou 230dp

Comment: Relacionado(duplicata?): [Ajustar Imagem/Bitmap à ImageView ou ajustar a ImageView à Imagem/Bitmap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/250563/2541)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agora entendi o  problema. Você tem duas opções, essa:

```
<ImageView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:adjustViewBounds="true"
   app:srcCompat="@mipmap/energiasolar_foto2" />
```

Ou essa:

```
<ImageView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:scaleType="fitXY"
   app:srcCompat="@mipmap/energiasolar_foto2" />
```

Usa na imagem `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` ou `android:scaleType="fitXY"`. Ajusta os outros elementos pra não sobrepor.

Comment: Vlw, funcionou.

Comment: é nóiz então, me dá um votinho aí :D